# Why does a switch statement on an enum throw 'not comparable to type' error?

Tags: typescript, switch-statement

While doing a Lynda tutorial on Typescript ( https://www.lynda.com/Visual-Studio-tutorials/TypeScript-types-part-2/543000/565613-4.html#tab ), I hit a snag. The sample code illustrates how switch statements work in TypeScript but the code that seems to work fine for the instructor throws a *Type 'x' is not comparable to type 'y'* error. Here's the code:

```
enum temperature{
    cold,
    hot
}

let temp = temperature.cold;

switch (temp) {
    case temperature.cold:
        console.log("Brrr....");
        break;
    case temperature.hot:
        console.log("Yikes...")
        break;
}
```

I get an error and squiggles under `case temperature.hot:` saying:

```
Type 'temperature.hot' is not comparable to type 'temperature.cold'
```

What gives?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

That's because the compiler already knows that the case `temperature.hot` will never happen: the variable `temp` is given the enum literal type `temperature.cold`, which can only be assigned that value itself (or null if there are no strict null checks). As `temperature.hot` is not a compatible value here, the compiler throws an error.

If we discard the information about the literal (by casting or retrieving the value from a function):

```
function how_cold(celsius: number): temperature {
    return celsius > 40 ? temperature.hot : temperature.cold;
}
```

The code will then compile:

```
let temp = how_cold(35); // type is "temperature"

switch (temp) {
    case temperature.cold:
        console.log("Brrr....");
        break;
    case temperature.hot:
        console.log("Yikes...")
        break;
}
```

Alternatively, prepending `+` to the value works because it converts the value to a number, which will also widen the type's scope and make it compatible with all enum variants, as well as other numbers.

```
let temp = temperature.cold;

switch (+temp) {
    case temperature.cold:
        console.log("Brrr....");
        break;
    case temperature.hot:
        console.log("Yikes...")
        break;
    case 5:
        console.log("What??");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Another possible reason could be if you check if the enum variable is not `null` but this also triggers if `enumVal` is `0`. This only holds true if the enum has the default numeric values (so first item gets the value of `0`)

```
if (!!enumVal) {
    switch (enumVal) {
         case EnumClass.First // the if clause automatically excludes the first item
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem was as @Kris mentioned.

I had to add

```
if (icon !== null) {
    switch (icon) {
```

or change the first value of the enum to be 1 instead of 0

```
export enum ICON_TYPE {
    ICON_A = 1,
    ICON_B = 2
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45197975) is very good however it does not give an example of casting. Here I use casting to disregard the compiler's knowledge of the constant `debug_level`.

```js
type DebugLevel = 'log' | 'warn' | 'error';

const debug_lvl: DebugLevel = 'warn';

switch((debug_lvl as DebugLevel)){
  case 'error':
    console.error(...args);
    break;

  case 'warn':
    console.warn(...args);
    break;

  case 'log':
    console.log(...args);
    break;
}
```