# Error with Typescript const string comparison

Tags: string, typescript, constants, tslint

This is actually preventing my Angular app from running. This is a derived example, the `const` I'm setting is just to test some values in a function, so there are ways around this, but it seems so odd I'd like to know what's going on.

The following code gives the tslint error `Type '"Red"' is not comparable to type '"Green"'.` Happens with `if` statements as well.

```
const color = 'Red'

switch(color) {
  case 'Red':
    //do something
  case 'Green':
    //something else
}
```

Why does is it using the strings as types? Why can't I compare a const string variable to a string? This seems like a bug.

Comment: `const color: string = 'Red'` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript Switch statement throws 'not comparable to type' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45197320/typescript-switch-statement-throws-not-comparable-to-type-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typescript has [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html), a type that represents a single value. Constant types will be inferred to the literal type representing the value that is being assigned to them. So when you declare `const color = 'Red'` the type of `color` will actually be the string literal type `'Red'` not the `string` type.

Typescript does this in order to check as much of your code as possible. In this case if you think about it, the `Green` case can't be reached from this code, so there is probably something invalid about this code (we don't usually want to write dead code).

If you want the type of the constant to be just `string`, you can type the constant manually:

```
const color: string = 'Red';
```

Comment: getting this error - [tslint] Type string trivially inferred from a string literal, remove type annotation (no-inferrable-types)

Comment: @j1s What can I say .. tslint has it wrong .. sure it will be inferred but it will be inferred to something else you don't want ... I always take tslint warnings with a grain of salt, they could be mistakes but not always, I'd argue this is one you can suppress if you really want the const to be string not the string literal type ..