# TypeScript: Enum.Value is not comparable to some other Enum.Value

Tags: typescript

I have placed an enum in a seperate file so I can use that enum across files

Enums.ts

```
export enum Category {
    NotDefined,        
    BackData,
    Testing,
    Simulated
}
```

In another file i try to use my enum. I am trying to write a simple if/else or switch.

If i set the value of category == Category.Testing vscode is happy.
If i try to set the value to something else e.g. "backData" as in the example below I get an error:

```
Type 'Category.Testing' is not comparable to type 'Category.BackData'
```

Example code:

```
import { Category } from '@app/model/Enums.ts';

public async SubmitForm(): Promise<Boolean> {
    var category: Category;
    category = Category.BackData;

    switch (category) {
      case (Category.Testing): {
        ...
      }
      default: {
        ...
      }
    }

    if (category == Category.Testing) {
      ...
    } else {
      ...
    }
}
```

The error when setting the enum to another value that testing

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does a switch statement on an enum throw 'not comparable to type' error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45197320/why-does-a-switch-statement-on-an-enum-throw-not-comparable-to-type-error)

Comment: It is the same question, but the answer i received if different that the answers suggest in that question. I will therefore choose not to mark it a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround (for testing purposes only) you can write:

```
category = Category.BackData as Category;
```

Answer (score 0):

Typescript enums are nominal or opaque meaning that they are globally unique and unassignable to other or other types even if they're both the same.

```
export type IsEqual<A, B> = [A] extends [B] ? [B] extends [A] ? true : false : false

enum Foo {
    Foo
}

enum Bar {
    Bar
}

enum FooStr {
    Foo  = "hello"
}

enum BarStr {
    Bar = "hello"
}

type WhatType = IsEqual<Foo, Bar> // false.
type WhatType1 = IsEqual<Foo.Foo, Bar.Bar> // false even though both are 0
type WhatType2 = IsEqual<FooStr.Foo, BarStr.Bar> // false even though both are "hello"
```